# Download encrypted webpage

Tags: python, string, cookies

Hi I have researched this but I can not find any answers this question. I need to download a sub directory of a web page to a string for a search, I know have to do this but the only problem is the site is encrypted and requires a login to acces the directory. I know I need to send the cookies to request the download but I am unsure how to do this. I am coding python. feel free to ask for more info.

Comment: Feel free to ask a question first, We are not here to question you what you want to question first.

Comment: If it requires a login, then the only extra thing is that you hit the login page with your credentials. All sites are encrypted, you don't have to bother about encryption. Just bother about correct url, and correct post parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import time

# All your cookie related things are done by this.
cookie_jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)


#POST Parameters for login page.
request_body_params = {'your_parameter_name': 'its_value', 'another_parameter_name': 'its_value'}


data_encoding = urllib.urlencode(request_body_params)
url_main = 'https://your_site.com/login'

main_request = urllib2.Request(url_main, data_encoding)

#Any headers required goes here.
main_request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')

# This is the response of login. You don't want to read this.
main_response = urllib2.urlopen(main_request)

# You want data from this link.
url_results = 'https://your_site.com/sub_directory'
results_response = urllib2.urlopen(url_results)

print results_response.read()
```

To check the POST Parameters, go to the site from a browser, click on 'View Source', go to 'Network' in view source. Then as you login in the browser, there will be network logs generated, click on the link and check out it's POST Parameters and headers.